# C++ equivalent of Rust's Result<T, E> type?

Tags: c++, boost, option-type, c++17

I like using std::experimental::optional in my C++ code, but the problem is value_or requires the default value to be of the same type as the optional's value.

This doesn't work very well when I want an optional that either contains an int or contains an error message.

I guess I could use a union struct that has a boolean to indicate if the value is there or it's an error, but it sure would be nice if C++ just had a `Result<T, E>` type like Rust.

Is there any such type? Why hasn't Boost implemented it?

Result is really much more useful than Option, and surely the people at Boost are aware of its existence. Maybe I'll go read the Rust implementation and then copy it to C++?

Ex:

```
// Function either returns a file descriptor for a listening socket or fails
// and returns a nullopt value.
// My issue: error messages are distributed via perror.
std::experimental::optional<int> get_tcp_listener(const char *ip_and_port);
// You can use value_or to handle error, but the error message isn't included!
// I have to write my own error logger that is contained within
// get_tcp_listener. I would really appreciate if it returned the error
// message on failure, rather than an error value.
int fd = get_tcp_listener("127.0.0.1:9123").value_or(-1);
// Rust has a type which does what I'm talking about:
let fd = match get_tcp_listener("127.0.0.1:9123") {
    Ok(fd) => fd,
    Err(msg) => { log_error(msg); return; },
}
```

Comment: Possibly the proposed `std::expected`, or another `Expected` type someone's implemented.

Comment: An expression in C++ must have a type known at compile time; it can't be either an `int` or a string.

Comment: How is one thing more useful than another thing when they solve completely unrelated, orthogonal problems? Is `vector` more useful than `cout`?

Comment: No there isn't, and thank God for that because that is such a terrible plan.

Comment: @Puppy don't like `expected`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), [`optional<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/optional) is an asymmetric type safe union of `T` and nothingness (`nullopt_t`).  You can query if it has a `T` with `explicit operator bool`, and get the `T` out with unary `*`.  The asymmetry means that optional "prefers" to be a `T`, which is why unqualified operations (like `*` or operator bool) refer to its `T`ness.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) [`variant<A,B,C>` from paper n4218](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4218.pdf) is a symmetric type safe union of `A`, `B` and `C` (etc).  `boost::variant` is always engaged, and `std::variant` is *almost* always engaged (in order to preserve some exception guarantees, it can become valueless by exception if the types it store don't have the right exception semantics).

As it is symmetric, there is no unique type for unary `*` to return, and `explicit operator bool` cannot say much of interest, so neither are supported.

Instead, you have to visit it, or query it for particular types.

In [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) [`std::expected<T, E>` from paper n4015](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4015.pdf) is an asymmetric type-safe union.  It is either a `T`, or an `E`.  But like `optional`, it "prefers" to be a `T`; it has an `explicit operator bool` that tells you if it is a `T`, and unary `*` gets the `T`.

In a sense, `expected<T,E>` is an `optional<T>`, but when empty instead of wasting the space it stores an `E`, which you can query.

`Result<T,E>` seems close to `expected<T,E>` (note that as of n4015, the order of parameters are swapped compared to `Result`, but the [published](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) version did not).

Comment: Wow thanks for the info! You guys have all been really helpful!

Comment: A very good concise explanation of optional vs variant vs expected. The proposal for expected seems to have similar content to the talk I posted, and references it in fact. Going through both is probably worthwhile, otherwise choose the medium you prefer.

Comment: Hi, expected is in C++23 so you can update your question if you think it might be interesting to mention.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Done!  I wasn't expecting it to show up that soon with the Covid-19 delays.

Answer (score 12):

What you are looking for is exactly Alexandrescu's Expected. I recommend listening to his talk for an in depth understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kaI4R0Ng4E8. He actually goes through the implementation line by line, and you can easily write it yourself and use it well after that.

Variant is a more general tool, it can be coerced to do what you want but you're better off with expected.

Comment: Thank you, this is more like what I was looking for!

Comment: "you can easily write it yourself and use it well after that" yes it's a very useful talk. in particular i've used his pattern in projects where we're supposed to avoid throwing exceptions. you can make a standard "error message" struct that plays the role of the exception, and try to make your class so that objects that are actually errors can be implicitly converted to a different type, or try to do it more like Haskell's maybe where you basically handle the thing with visitors. if you implement it yourself instead of using variant, you can also make it handle move_ctors correctly

Answer (score 10):

If not only boost is involved u can use [result](https://github.com/oktal/result). This is nice single header container.

Answer (score 4):

`optional` by design either contains a value of some type or nothing.

You may be looking for something like [`Boost::Variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant.html).

This is not yet part of the standard library, although something like it may be eventually.

Comment: This is almost a perfect solution, but I think expected is more suited to the task. However, expected<T, E> is not in any standard yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since this was asked, the C++23 standard's [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) does exactly this. A summarizing quote from Cpp Reference:

> The class template `std::expected` provides a way to store either of two values. An object of `std::expected` at any given time either holds an *expected* value of type **T**, or an *unexpected* value of type **E**. `std::expected` is never valueless.